# Create a data frame with the common columns of a data frame list - R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, merge

I need to get the common columns of a data frame list separated in different data frames. Please look at the following example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Dates = c('01-01-2020','02-01-2020','03-01-2020'), col1 = c(1,2,3), col2 = c(3,2,1))
df2 <- data.frame(Dates = c('01-01-2020','02-01-2020','03-01-2020'), col1 = c(4,5,6), col2 = c(6,5,4))
df3 <- data.frame(Dates = c('01-01-2020','02-01-2020'), col1 = c(7,8), col2 = c(8,7))
ldf <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

The desired output would be the following two data frames:

```
df_col1:
Date       df1 df2 df3
01-01-2020   1   4   7
02-01-2020   2   5   8
03-01-2020   3   6  NA

df_col2:
Date       df1 df2 df3
01-01-2020   3   6   8
02-01-2020   2   5   7
03-01-2020   1   4  NA
```

Of course, `ldf` is actually way longer, but the number of columns is fixed to 5, so the number of outputs is also fixed (4). This means I wouldn't mind if I use a block of code for each output.

I've tried several things but none seems to work. I'm using base R and hope to find a solution wihtout additional packages.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We bind the `list` elements with `bind_rows` from `dplyr`, then loop over the 'col' columns, along with the common 'Dates', reshape to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider` and `rename` if needed

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
newdf <- bind_rows(ldf) 
out <- map(names(newdf)[-1], ~ 
            newdf %>%
                select(Dates, .x) %>%
                mutate(rn = rowid(Dates)) %>% 
                pivot_wider(names_from =rn, values_from = !! rlang::sym(.x))  %>%
        rename_at(-1, ~ str_c('df', seq_along(.))))
```

-output

```
out
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  Dates        df1   df2   df3
#  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 01-01-2020     1     4     7
#2 02-01-2020     2     5     8
#3 03-01-2020     3     6    NA

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  Dates        df1   df2   df3
#  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 01-01-2020     3     6     8
#2 02-01-2020     2     5     7
#3 03-01-2020     1     4    NA
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
newdf <- do.call(rbind, ldf)
f1 <- function(dat, colName) {
      lst1 <- split(dat[[colName]], dat$Dates)
       do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1))))
 }
     
f1(newdf, 'col1')
f1(newdf, 'col2')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @akrun, but I'm looking for something on Base R. Either way, I'll keep this in mind if nothing else cames up.

Comment: Thanks akrun! Saddly the output in the actual data gets mixed up.. I don't know why this happens though.

Comment: @Juanito Not clear about the case.  The example works if you have the data similar to the example

Comment: I can't paste all the data here and I'm still not capable of reproducing an example, but with your answer I'm getting misplaced values (a colum with values on dates that should be empty).. I'm stll looking into it

Comment: @Juanito In my code, it is also appending `NA` at the end for the `list` ('lst1'), where the length is less than the max length of each element

Comment: I know, that's why I'm unable to determine why is that I'm getting this result...

Comment: @Juanito Can you edit in your post with the dput of a small example that shows the issue

Comment: Sure, I'm trying to understand what is happening first, then I'll update. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There, I had an issue with the data itself. I'm sorry about the confusion. It is working fine now, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Juanito Thank you for the update.  I was also thinking how that could go wrong because the code is tested vigorously in the past

Answer (score 2):

Another Base R option is to do:

```
m <- Reduce(function(x,y)merge(x, y, by='Dates', all=TRUE), ldf)
lapply(split.default(m[-1], sub("\\..*", "", names(m[-1]))), cbind, m[1])
```

Comment: Thanks Onyambu! The issue with your solution is when you have more columns, the name of the new ones repeats throwing an "column names XXXXX are duplicated in the result"

Answer (score 1):

Another wordy approach using `base R`:

```
#Code
names(ldf) <- paste0('df',1:length(ldf))
#Function
myfun <- function(x) {
  y <- reshape(x,direction = 'long',
               v.names='col',
               idvar = 'Dates',varying = list(2:3))
  return(y)
}
z <- do.call(rbind,lapply(ldf,myfun))
z$Data <- gsub("\\..*","",rownames(z))
rownames(z) <- NULL
#Reshape
z2 <- reshape(z,idvar = c('Dates','time'),timevar = 'Data')
#List
List <- split(z2,z2$time)
List
```

Output:

```
List
$`1`
       Dates time col.df1 col.df2 col.df3
1 01-01-2020    1       1       4       7
2 02-01-2020    1       2       5       8
3 03-01-2020    1       3       6      NA

$`2`
       Dates time col.df1 col.df2 col.df3
4 01-01-2020    2       3       6       8
5 02-01-2020    2       2       5       7
6 03-01-2020    2       1       4      NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Duck! The issue with your alternative is when you have more columns. Is there a way to generalize that?